# listview with the names of shared preferences and link them

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

i am developing an android-application in which i have one activity that creates 
Shared Preferences.

in the other activity i just want to retrieve the names of the shared preferences created by the first activity and populate those names in a list view.
and i also want to link those names(in the listview) with the actual shared preferences.

Comment: the other activity doesn't know the number of preferences present. still it has to retrieve all of them in the listview

Answer (score 2):

In the other activity, use [SharedPreferences.getAll](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) to get all values from shared preferences:

```
Map<String,?> values = prefs.getAll();
```

Then, you can iterate through `values` to get strings you want. Probably you can store those strings to an array. Next, initialize an `ArrayAdapter` to let the listview populate those data. Similar code is here:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.list_item, strings);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: i dont want the values from the shared preferences.... i just want the list of shared preferences that i have created to be viewed in the list view. then i can select a particular preference to be viewed....?

Comment: When you create your shared preferences, you already know their names right? So, you can just store those names into an array or something when the first time you create them.